# How to link to overloaded methods in Javadoc comments?

Tags: generics, methods, overloading, javadoc, variadic-functions

I have overloads of a method and want to provide links within their Javadoc comments to the others. But I have problems with generics and/or varargs. I hoped I could write it like this:

```
/**
 * @see {@link #method(Object[], Object[])}
 * @see {@link #method(Collection, Object[])}
 */
public <T> void method(T object, T... furtherObjects) {}

/**
 * @see {@link #method(Object, Object[])}
 * @see {@link #method(Collection, Object[])}
 */
public <T> void method(T[] objects, T... furtherObjects) {}

/**
 * @see {@link #method(Object[], Object[])}
 * @see {@link #method(Collection, Object[])}
 */
public <T> void method(Collection<T> objects, T... furtherObjects) {}
```

But every link results in the first method.
Using Eclipse.